# Registration form: 404 error

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I have created a registration form. And I don't know why now it doesn't work anymore.
Now I receive a 404 error:

> > Type Status Report
>
> Message /HotelReservation/Registration
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

This is my

> Registration.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hotel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author OOPs
 */
public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String s1 = request.getParameter("ename");
        String s2 = request.getParameter("nname");
        String s3 = request.getParameter("pname");
        String s4 = request.getParameter("usid");
        String s5 = request.getParameter("gm");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. 
            out.println(s1);
           out.println(s2);
           out.println(s3);
           out.println(s4);
           out.println(s5);*/
       //    out.println(s1);
           //concetivity...............

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        out.println("driver loaded");
     Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");
        out.println("Connect");
      Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
          out.println("conncetion successfull");
          st.executeUpdate("insert into register (email,name,pass) values ('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"')");
          out.println("<h1> Register sucsefulltttt </h1>");

          response.sendRedirect("thankyou.jsp"); 

        }catch(Exception e){
        out.println("nahiiiiiiiiiiiii" +e);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

And this is my

> registration.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Registration</title>
        <style>
        @import url( css/default.css);
        </style> 

    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="nav">       
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="prenotazione.jsp">Prenotazione</a>
        <a href="Room.html">Camere</a>
        <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
        <a href="registration.jsp">Registrazione</a>
    </div>     
        <script>
       function validate()
            {
                if(document.getElementById("ename").value=="")
                {
                    alert("blank");
        return false;        
        }
                return true;
            }
        </script>



  <h2>Registrazione</h2>

  <form action="Registration" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
      <div class="gender">
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-envelope "></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="ename" id="ename" placeholder="Email" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
  <input type="text" name="nname" id="nname" placeholder="Name" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
  <input type="password" name="pname" id="pname" placeholder="Password" required/>
  <br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign UP"  name="b1"> </input>
  <input class="button" type=button onClick="location.href='login.jsp'" value="Login"  name="b" > </input>





  </form>
  <div id="footer">
<h4>Hotel Reservation </h4>
Viale Marco Polo, 81 Roma
tel: +39 01 0000000 | info@hotelreservation.it
P.IVA 000000001
</div>  
  </div>    


    </body>


</html>
```

How can I solve it in your opinion? Thanks

EDIT:
This is my :

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Hotelbooking</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hotelbooking</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Hotelbooking</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hotelbooking</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hotelbooking</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Login</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Logout</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Logout</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <display-name>Registration</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Registration</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /HotelReservation/Registration
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[myProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1u0N.png)

Comment: add your `web.xml` file and check if you have `thankyou.jsp`

Comment: 404 error is due to a file that doesn't exist, so check your links and files

Comment: I add this:

    <display-name>thankyou</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>thankyou</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.thankyou</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>thankyou</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/thankyou</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

But not change

Comment: Post you project structure and web.xml file. It will help us to detect your problem

Comment: @AvijitBarua I have done!!

Comment: Where have put your jsp page ?

Comment: in the WebContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `doGet` method to forward at `registration.jsp` like this

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
request.getRequestDispatcher("/registration.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

Another thing in error message map showing `/HotelReservation/Registration`
but in web.xml file servlet mapping is `/registration`. So hit correct url